# Compile OpenCV on Mac with FFMPEG instead of Quicktime

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, ffmpeg, g++

I'm developing some code that will run on Linux with OpenCV and FFMPEG.  I would like to use my Mac to develop this code and I need the FFMPEG functionality on the Mac.

I've been able to run configure like this:

```
./configure --without-quicktime --with-ffmpeg --without-python --disable-apps CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/local/include LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/share -L/usr/local/lib"
```

but when I run make I get this error:

```
Extracting /Users/adamb/opencv/trunk/opencv/src/./.libs/lib_cxcore.a
(cd .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a && ar x /Users/adamb/opencv/trunk/opencv/src/./.libs/lib_cxcore.a)
g++ -dynamiclib -single_module  -o .libs/libcxcore.2.dylib  .libs/dummy.o  .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxalloc.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxarithm.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxarray.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxcmp.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxconvert.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxcopy.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxdatastructs.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxdrawing.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxdxt.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxerror.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cximage.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxlapack.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxlogic.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxlut.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxmathfuncs.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxmatmul.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxmatrix.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxmean.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxmeansdv.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxminmaxloc.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxnorm.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxouttext.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxpersistence.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxrand.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxsumpixels.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxsvd.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxswitcher.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxtables.o .libs/libcxcore.lax/lib_cxcore.a/cxutils.o   -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/share -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lpthread -ldl -lm  -march=prescott -msse -install_name  /usr/local/lib/libcxcore.2.dylib -Wl,-compatibility_version -Wl,3 -Wl,-current_version -Wl,3.0
    Undefined symbols:
      "_dgesdd_", referenced from:
      _cvSVD in cxsvd.o
      _cvSVD in cxsvd.o
  "_sgelsd_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_ssyevr_", referenced from:
      _cvEigenVV in cxlapack.o
      _cvEigenVV in cxlapack.o
  "_dgetrf_", referenced from:
      _cvDet in cxlapack.o
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
  "_dgetri_", referenced from:
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
  "_sgesdd_", referenced from:
      _cvSVD in cxsvd.o
      _cvSVD in cxsvd.o
  "_dgels_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_dgesv_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_sgetrf_", referenced from:
      _cvDet in cxlapack.o
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
  "_sgetri_", referenced from:
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
  "_dpotrf_", referenced from:
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_dpotri_", referenced from:
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
  "_dpotrs_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_sgels_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_spotrf_", referenced from:
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_spotri_", referenced from:
      _cvInvert in cxlapack.o
  "_sgesv_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_spotrs_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_dgelsd_", referenced from:
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
      _cvSolve in cxlapack.o
  "_dsyevr_", referenced from:
      _cvEigenVV in cxlapack.o
      _cvEigenVV in cxlapack.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libcxcore.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried using a newer version of OpenCV, 1.1pre1 and I get a similar error but with different symbols.  I'm using the same ./configure as above.

```
Extracting /Users/adamb/Downloads/opencv-1.1.0/otherlibs/highgui/./.libs/lib_highgui.a
(cd .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a && ar x /Users/adamb/Downloads/opencv-1.1.0/otherlibs/highgui/./.libs/lib_highgui.a)
g++ -dynamiclib  -o .libs/libhighgui.2.0.0.dylib  .libs/dummy.o  .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/bitstrm.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/cvcap.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/cvcap_ffmpeg.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/cvcap_images.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_base.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_bmp.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_exr.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_imageio.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_jpeg.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_jpeg2000.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_png.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_pxm.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_sunras.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/grfmt_tiff.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/image.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/loadsave.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/precomp.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/utils.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/window.o .libs/libhighgui.lax/lib_highgui.a/window_carbon.o   -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/share -L/usr/local/lib ../../cxcore/src/.libs/libcxcore.dylib /opt/local/lib/libavformat.dylib /opt/local/lib/libavcodec.dylib ../../cv/src/.libs/libcv.dylib /Users/adamb/Downloads/opencv-1.1.0/cxcore/src/.libs/libcxcore.dylib /opt/local/lib/libjasper.dylib /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib -lavformat -lavcodec -lpthread -ldl -lm  -march=prescott -msse2 -framework ApplicationServices -Wl,-framework -Wl,Carbon -install_name  /usr/local/lib/libhighgui.2.dylib -compatibility_version 3 -current_version 3.0 -Wl,-single_module
Undefined symbols:
  "_av_rescale_q", referenced from:
      icv_av_write_frame_FFMPEG(AVFormatContext*, AVStream*, unsigned char*, unsigned int, AVFrame*)in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
  "_img_convert", referenced from:
      CvCapture_FFMPEG::retrieveFrame()       in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::writeFrame(_IplImage const*)  in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      icv_alloc_picture_FFMPEG(int, int, int, bool)in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvCapture_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
  "_av_freep", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::close()      in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
  "_av_malloc", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::open(char const*, int, double, CvSize, bool)in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
  "_av_sub_q", referenced from:
      CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::open(char const*, int, double, CvSize, bool)in cvcap_ffmpeg.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

If I add --enable-shared=no and OpenCV will compile, but then my programs won't run...

Any suggestions as to how to get either of these to compile with the default --enable-shared?

Answer (score 2):

Your link line is missing -lavutil -lavcodec.

Answer (score 1):

I installed OpenCV and FFmpeg using [homebrew](http://abhinay.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/macports-to-homebrew-new-packaging-system-for-mac-os-x/) and both work Ok.

Comment: Ditto, though I'm still not sure _which_ codecs work. DIV3 yeilds garbage, for exampe

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this, but do you have the ffmpeg libraries installed on your system?  I don't believe they're included with OpenCV.